# Bugs with Animation of tank. Blender 2.83 stl

Tags: animation, rigging, physics, properties, rigidbody

Well, I'm trying to do a tank like in this tutorial :https://youtu.be/q5fjslhomsI

1.There are often bugs with metric system. It just doesn't work properly that good!

[image]

C'mon I have to make stiffness and damping more then 10000 to make them work nice...

2.There is a bug with Timeline.
I use McGavish's .blend file to make every thing right. But tank's body always goes back in it's first position when i press "pause".

[image]

3.Also Emptyies don't go with body cause of lags or bugs. There are 2 examples:

[image]

4.When I use Metric system, I need to increase "Steps per second" to 1000 and "Solver iterations" to 400. Or tracks will run away or go through the wheel...

I am very tired and have been trying to make animation for 7 days. Each day like 12 hours. )-;

Answer (score 1):

So after 8th day of researching .. i found really interesting Bug...

It was made in Blender 2.9.1

https://youtu.be/vxjTQ7TOz1E Bug with constraints and parent objects

Answer (score 0):

So solution not found.

BUT there is solution to avoid bugs:

DO NOT click on the buttons in the section of cache!

[image]